# Split data frame and have new row numbers

Tags: r, dataframe

When I split my data into two new data frames, the row numbers of the two new data frames will index the original data frame.

For example if `dfA` has row numbers 1, 2, 3, 4; I want to create two new data frames based on alternating rows (so rows 1 & 3 go to `dfB` and rows 2 & 4 go to `dfC`). But I want the row numbers to have new indexes in `dfB` and `dfC`, so that actually both `dfB` and `dfC` have 1 & 2 as the row index.

The reason this is a problem is that when I split my (actually much larger df) into `A` and `B`, whenever I try to access specific data points, the number that appears in `row.names` is different from what R reads as the actual row number. Any ideas?

Comment: please show what your want with example data & code.

Comment: If you actually use row names, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: R is column based and row names often are ignored/stripped by certain functions, often silently.  Your best bet is to convert the row names into an explicit variable like `ID` and then use that as your indexing variable.  It will be much easier to work with.

Comment: `rownames() <- NULL` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want

```
rownames(df) <- NULL
```

i.e,

```
sampl1
   v1 v2 v3 v4
1  23  4  0  0
2  61 15  1  0
3 271 17  0  1
4  55 12  0  1
5  60  8  0  0
```

Subset data

```
subset.sampl1 <- subset(sampl1, sampl1$v4 == 1)
subset.sampl1
#   v1 v2 v3 v4
#3 271 17  0  1
#4  55 12  0  1
```

Then setting rownames to NULL,

```
rownames(subset.sampl1) <- NULL
subset.sampl1
#   v1 v2 v3 v4
#1 271 17  0  1
#2  55 12  0  1
```